# How to update a column between 2 lists

Tags: sharepoint

Good morning all,

I am having difficulties on sharepoint online.

I have a list called "stock"
which is structured as follows:

Category | model | amount

Car      | Golf  | 4

Another another list called recording where there are many movements (entry exit)
it is structured as follows:

Category | model | Entrance | Exit

Car      | Golf  |          | 2

Car      | Golf  |    1     |

Is it possible to update the stock list according to the recording list?

here in my case I have a quantity of 4 with an output of 2 units and 1 input. I would like the stock column according to
updates and displays an amount of 1.

I hope that I managed to explain my request to you.

Thanks for your feedback;)

Comment: you could create a Sharepoint workflow/MS flow that adds entry/exits for a particular model/category and subtracts that value from amount value in stock list, on every create or update event for recording list and update amount in stock list for that model/category

Answer (score 0):

best and easiest way to achieve this is to use power automate flow which You could create on list recording list. You could create the flow on add/modify item on list. In the flow You can do any logic in the flow to calculate the stock and do the needed operations to update it.

Please be aware that the flow runs asynchronous and after some time so it will not be the best option for validations if You want to check if the stock number is above 0 to allow a new recording for that item

Comment: Hello Adam, thank you for your return.

I will create a flow with your solution, i thinks is a great ideas. Thanks :)